# How to execute the html reflecting the changes i have done with PHP?

Tags: html

I want to change all the occurrences of a word with another word using php. I want my HTML code to reflect the changes I have done accordingly.

```
<?php
$strhtml = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>time</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="post">Hello, How are you</p>

</body>
</html>';
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);
$elm = $dochtml->getElementById('post');
$c = $elm->nodeValue;
$d= date("H");
if ($d<11)
str_replace("Hello","Good Morning",$c)
?>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error in the code. I am just asking for the solution such that my HTML page gets reflected with the changes I am making using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$dochtml->saveHTML()` function to parse DOMDocument object to html content. This code works for me.

```
<?php
    $strhtml = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="post">Hello, How are you</p>

    </body>
    </html>';
    $dochtml = new DOMDocument();
    $dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);
    $elm = $dochtml->getElementById('post');
    $c = $elm->nodeValue;
    $d= date("H");
    if ($d<11){
        $c = str_replace("Hello","Good Morning",$c);
    }

    $dochtml->getElementById('post')->nodeValue = $c;
    echo $dochtml->saveHTML();
    ?>
```